# What is the best way to limit docker container memory cache?

Tags: docker, memory

I have a spark job with setting `spark.executor.memory=4G` and setting docker memory limitation=5G

And I monitoring memory usage by `docker stats`

`$ docker stats --format="{{.MemUsage}}"
1.973GiB / 5GiB`

Usage of memory = RSS+Cache = 930MB + 1.xGB = 1.97GB

The cache size increasing until triggering OOM killer then my job will be failed.

Currently, I release cache manually by typing command

`$ sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

It works for me, but is there any better way to limit docker memory cache size or dropping memory cache automatically

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? If so, would you mind sharing it? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: This might be a general matter of how to limit cache usage on Linux, not specific to docker. Consider this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253816/restrict-size-of-buffer-cache-in-linux